# Operator '>' cannot be applied to types 'boolean' and '{ return: Observable<any>; }' error

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm currently following an Angular tutorial and I've gotten this error in a service component.

Here's my code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NgserviceService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { 

    fetchProductListFromRemote():Observable<any> {
      return this.http.get<any>("localhost:8083/getproductlist");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i dont think you need the `<any>` after `get`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not write a method in the contructor. Close the constructor before your fetchProductListFromRemote method.